# Is it possible to see only the commits in a particular branch in git?

Tags: git

Usually 'git log' shows all the commits contributing to the current point, even those commits that came from branches merged into the current branch.

Is it possible to issue a command to only see the commits in a particular branch?  That is, if there is an integration branch where everything is merged just before shipping, is there any git command to see only those commits in that branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This (which you already know) specifies the set of commits reachable from integration:

```
g log integration
```

The "^" operation can be used for everything NOT reachable via this commit (rev). For example, everything reachable by integration and exclude everything also reachable by master:

```
g log ^master integration
```

The common shorthand for that (integration but not master):

```
g log master..integration
```

You can use multiple exclude specifiers (integration but not master or devel):

```
g log ^master ^devel integration
```

Hopefully that covers enough to give you what you need. This information is in `man git-rev-parse` in the **SPECIFYING REVISIONS** and **SPECIFYING RANGES** section.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
git checkout <branch>
git diff master <commit just before the merge to master>
```

There should be a way to automate getting the name of the commit just before the merge to master, which would let you make this into a macro or alias.

Also, check out `git log -p -m --first-parent` as mentioned in the `git help log` docs; it might do something similar enough.

Comment: `--first-parent` is almost certainly what the OP wants. This will cause the revision tree walking to follow only the first parent of merge commits. When you merge `topic` into `integration`, the (merged-into) commit from `integration` is the first parent, and the (merged) commit from `topic` is the second parent. Assuming you've been consistent about which way you merge, that ought to list the desired commits. (The OP is asking about seeing commits (plural), so it's `log` not `diff` they want.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure. The idea of a branch in git is simply a pointer to a location in the tree (not a completely separate line of development like in svn etc.).

You can however do a git branch `--no-merged` to see what branches need to be integrated into the current one.

I suppose it's possible to write something that will give you all commits which are there *only* behind the current HEAD and nowhere else. I'm not sure how though.